How to Correct Poisson-Distributed Data for a Scaling Factor while Maintaining Consistency in Sums?
I have a set of independent observations $ k_1, k_2, \dots, k_n $, which I assume originate from Poisson distributions with means $ f \mu_1, f \mu_2, \dots, f \mu_n $, where $ f $ is a scaling factor that affects all means uniformly.
I would like to transform these observations to remove the effect of the factor $ f $ while preserving the deviation patterns. Specifically, if $ k_i $ is much higher than its expected value $ f \mu_i $, I want the transformed value $ \tilde{k}_i $ to reflect a similar deviation relative to $ \mu_i $ (without the factor $ f $).
Initial Attempt
My first idea was to use the CDF of the Poisson distribution for this transformation. For each observation $ k_i $, I applied the following transformation:
$$
\tilde{k}_i := F^{-1}_{\mu_i}(F_{\mu_i f} (k_i)),
$$
where $ F_{\mu}(x) $ is the CDF of a Poisson distribution with mean $ \mu $.
Problem
I noticed an inconsistency when summing the transformed variables. Specifically, the sum of the transformed values $ \tilde{k}_i $ does not match the expected transformation of the sum of the original values. That is,
$$
\sum \tilde{k}_i \neq F^{-1}_{ \sum \mu_i}\left( F_{\sum \mu_i f} \left( \sum k_i \right) \right).
$$
In my experiments, the left-hand side (sum of individual transformations) is always higher and scales with $ n $ and affected by $f$. This inconsistency is problematic since we would like the sum of the transformed variable to be corrected as well.
Additional Observations

I do not observe this inconsistency if I replace the Poisson distribution with normal distribution.
Smoothing the Poisson CDF reduces but does not fully eliminate the problem.

Questions

Why does this inconsistency occur? What is the underlying reason that the transformation is inconsistent when summing Poisson-distributed variables?
What would be the best approach to transform the variables in a way that is consistent with both individual observations and their sum?

